# Problem when defining a function in python with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, python-requests

Im making a program that searches a website for a specific word.
Exampel : Word: football on the website fifa.com.
I made it in a terminal which was very easy. Now i want to make a program using tkinter and it wont work.
The problem i have is when i run my program it says

> File "c:/Users/Censored/Desktop/PythonFolder/Program.py", line 22, in 
>       temp = Button(root, text='GO', command=searchgo)
>   NameError: name 'searchgo' is not defined

This is my code:

```
import requests
import re
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('WordCounter')
root.configure(bg='#2f3136')
root.geometry('700x700')
root.resizable(False, False)

# Buttons
e1 = Entry(root, width='35')
label1 = Label(root, text='Write The Word You Want To Search For', bg='#2f3136', fg='white',)

e2 = Entry(root, width='35')
label2 = Label(root, text='Write the websites URL', bg='#2f3136', fg='white',)

temp = Button(root, text='GO', command=searchgo)
# Buttons on screen
label1.grid(row='1', column='1',padx='10')
e1.grid(row='2', column='1', padx='10')

label2.grid(row='1', column='2', padx='10')
e2.grid(row='2', column='2', padx='10')

temp.pack()

# Define Functions
def searchgo():
    word = e1.get()
    URL = e2.get()
    page = requests.get(URL).text
    print(page.find(word))

root.mainloop()
```

Thanks for helping me!

Comment: Why is it solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has couple of bugs,

1. Define the function `searchgo` before you assign the callback to your button
2. In this code, better use `grid` to place you button instead of `place` or you get the following error

`cannot use geometry manager pack inside . (root) which already has slaves managed by grid`

The reason of this error is that, *you cannot use pack and grid geometry managers inside the same master window* (root in this program). Since you have used `grid` for most of the widgets, use `grid` for placing the button also.

Also, in case you are not aware, in `grid` geometry manager `row` and `column` position values start at `0` and not `1`

Here is the code:

```py
import requests
import re
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('WordCounter')
root.configure(bg='#2f3136')
root.geometry('700x700')
root.resizable(False, False)

# Buttons
e1 = Entry(root, width='35')
label1 = Label(root, text='Write The Word You Want To Search For', bg='#2f3136', fg='white',)

e2 = Entry(root, width='35')
label2 = Label(root, text='Write the websites URL', bg='#2f3136', fg='white',)

# Define Functions
def searchgo():
    word = e1.get()
    URL = e2.get()
    page = requests.get(URL).text
    print(page.find(word))

temp = Button(root, text='GO', command=searchgo)

# Buttons on screen
label1.grid(row='0', column='0',padx='10')
e1.grid(row='1', column='0', padx='10')

label2.grid(row='0', column='1', padx='10')
e2.grid(row='1', column='1', padx='10')

# use the grid manager to place your button
temp.grid(row='1', column='2', padx='10')

root.mainloop()
```

I have tried explaining the changes I made with some theory. I hope you understand!

Comment: Thank you i got it to work and understood what i did.

Answer (score 0):

Should the function be defined before you assigne it as Button attribute?
This will raise same exception:

```
class A:

def __init__(self, something):
    self.something = something

a = A(func)

def func():
    return
```

But, this works as expected:

```
def func():
    return


class A:

    def __init__(self, something):
        self.something = something

    a = A(func)
```